# Mongodb see previous database queries which removed any document from my database

Tags: mongodb, logging, system-profiler

I was reading about Mongodb System Profiler where it logs all mongodb queries. But is there any query by which i can see past queries which `removed` any document from my database like `findandremove`.

Below is the query I tried but it logged all past queries.

```
db.system.profile.find().pretty()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it like this:

```
db.system.profile.find({"op": "remove"}).pretty()
```

This assume that you have enable full profiling with `db.setProfilingLevel(2)` before running the `remove()` operation